# Ban certain users by using ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST (=[]) and getting data from a .txt file

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-allauth

I am using Django and All-auth. I want to restrict users to take certain usernames. I know that it is done through writing the following in  settings.py.

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST (=[])

But I want to take this list from a .txt file. Should I read the .txt file in my settings.py and then populate the ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST (=[]) list? Or there is some other way that is more reasonable and considered as a best practice?

Comment: https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ look at this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can just read in the text file in your settings file.

Its a common practice done where people will often load in a json file that contains values for a load of different settings that may change depending on environment.